# Wordpress - Determine if a menu item has children

Tags: php, wordpress

I've searched for hours and cannot come up with what I thought would be a simple thing. I am building my very first Wordpress site locally. I'm making a function for my functions.php file based on [this howto](https://digwp.com/2011/11/html-formatting-custom-menus/) but I need it to have submenus. I have created a custom menu inside Wordpress with 2 levels.

I need to add HTML code (not a CSS class) to an item if it is a parent item.

Bonus points if you can tell me how people know what attributes/properties are available to a menu item (such as title and url) - I can't find a reference to that anywhere!

Here is my current code, which is currently displaying all menu items as top-level items.

```
function clean_custom_main_menu() {
    $menu_name = 'main-menu'; // specify custom menu slug
    $menu_list = '<ul id="menu">' ."\n";

    if ($menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu_name)) { 
        $count = 0;
        $submenu = false;

        foreach ((array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item) {
            $title = $menu_item->title;
            $url = $menu_item->url;
            $classes = $menu_item->classes; // does not work
            $has_children = $menu_item->has_children;  //does not work
            $parent_id = 0;

            // check if this item is a parent item with children
            //if ( $menu_item->menu_item_parent && $menu_item->menu_item_parent > 0 ) {
            //if(in_array('menu-item-has-children', $classes)){
            if ($has_children) {
                $parent_id = $menu_item->ID;
            }
            // if this item has a parent ID, it's a second-level item
            if ($parent_id != 0 && $parent_id == $menu_item->menu_item_parent ) {
               $submenu = true;
            }

            if (!$has_children) {
               // if this item has no submenu, write top-level code
                $menu_list .= "\t". '<li><a href="'. $url .'">'. $title .'</a></li>' ."\n";
            }
            // the "else" is not currently being hit
            //else {
            //    $menu_list .= "\t" . '<li><a href="#">' . $title . '<span class="arrow-down"></span></a></li>' . "\n";
           //    $menu_list .= '<ul class="sub">';
            //    // foreach (child) do children
            //    $menu_list .= '</ul>';
            //    $menu_list .= '</li>';
            //}
        }
    } else {
         $menu_list .= '<!-- no list defined -->';
    }
    $menu_list .= "\t". '</ul>' ."\n";
    echo $menu_list;
}
```

Desired output:

```
 <ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">About <span class="arrow-down"></span></a>
    <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="/about/services.html">Our Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/what-we-do.html">What We Do</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
    <a href="/top-level-item/">Top-Level Item</a>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Top-Level Item with Children <span class="arrow-down"></span></a>
    <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="/top-level-item2/item1">Sub Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/top-level-item2/item2">Sub Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/top-level-item2/item3">Sub Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="/top-level-item2/item4">Sub Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please note: I do not want to use walkers. I am certain it can be done somehow since I had this working at one point, but lost everything when Wordpress decided to update the theme I made - to a totally different one from web-land, erasing all my files. D'oh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that people have contributed how to build items with submenus right on the Wordpress documentation for the function I was using, [wp_get_nav_menu_items()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/#Building_simple_menu_list). Those got me started but they weren't exactly quite right, since I had the extra span tags and wanted to close my A tags in different places, but I was able to ultimately get things working. Here is my final code based on those comments:

```
function clean_custom_main_menu() {
    $menu_name = 'main-menu'; // specify custom menu slug
    $menu_list = '<ul id="menu">' ."\n";

    if ($menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu_name)) { 
        $count = 0;
        $submenu = false;
        $parent_id = 0;
        $previous_item_has_submenu = false;

        foreach ((array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item) {
            $title = $menu_item->title;
            $url = $menu_item->url;

            // check if it's a top-level item
            if ($menu_item->menu_item_parent == 0) {
                $parent_id = $menu_item->ID;
               // write the item but DON'T close the A or LI until we know if it has children!
                $menu_list .= "\t". '<li><a href="'. $url .'">'. $title;
            }

            // if this item has a (nonzero) parent ID, it's a second-level (child) item
            else {
                if ( !$submenu ) { // first item
                    // add the dropdown arrow to the parent
                    $menu_list .= '<span class="arrow-down"></span></a>' . "\n";
                    // start the child list
                    $submenu = true;
                    $previous_item_has_submenu = true;
                    $menu_list .= "\t\t" . '<ul class="sub">' ."\n";
               }

                $menu_list .= "\t\t\t" . '<li>';
                $menu_list .= '<a href="'.$url.'" class="title">'.$title.'</a>';
                $menu_list .= '</li>' ."\n";

                // if it's the last child, close the submenu code
                if ( $menu_items[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && $submenu ){
                    $menu_list .= "\t\t" . '</ul></li>' ."\n";
                    $submenu = false;
                }
            }

            // close the parent (top-level) item
            if (empty($menu_items[$count + 1]) || $menu_items[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id )
            {
               if ($previous_item_has_submenu)
                {
                    // the a link and list item were already closed
                    $previous_item_has_submenu = false; //reset
                }
                else {
                    // close a link and list item
                    $menu_list .= "\t" . '</a></li>' . "\n";
                }
            }

            $count++;
        }
    } else {
         $menu_list .= '<!-- no list defined -->';
    }
    $menu_list .= "\t". '</ul>' ."\n";
    echo $menu_list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**API**

Try doing var_dump( $menu_items ) and you'll see that the menu items are posts of post_type "nav_menu_item" so they have the same api as post.

**Count Children**

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9374/get-the-post-children-count-of-a-post shows a way of accessing child post count using $wpdb. You could do this with get_posts by setting the parent_id to the parent item and post_type to nav_menu_item and then count the results.

**Classes**

The post object has a classes array. Since this wasn't working for you, I'd double check how you are trying to access/use that array and if that doesn't help, try investigating the walker functions for help with your custom implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The object does have a classes array, but it is always empty. I was trying to do `if(in_array('menu-item-has-children', $item->classes) && $depth != 0)`, but since the array was empty it didn't work. The var_dump was very enlightening. The parent objects have no awareness of their children, but the children know about their parent. I will try to work on this again tomorrow and let you know how it goes.